# How to treat wood to use in a deck

Tags: wood, deck, pressure-treated

I'd like to build a small (6'x8') floating deck for my yard. The deck would be resting on gravel. Ideally I'd like to use pressure treated wood, but a few of the pieces will need cuts, and my local store will only cut untreated wood. So I plan to use untreated wood for the deck.

What can I do to protect untreated wood from rotting, etc. Can it be stained?  What product should I use?

Comment: Using the wrong wood for the job just because of a few cuts seems like a bad solution.  Getting an inexpensive or used saw and using the correct wood is what you should do.

Comment: What he said.  You can get a handsaw at a garage sale for the price of a coffee, and a circular saw for not much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason it's called *pressure* treated--there's no good way to replicate that with a surface treatment. Anything you do will last a small fraction of the time it would have. Unless, that is, you live in the desert.

If you're set on your plan, any quality deck or siding sealer product will give some protection, especially if you apply it to all faces *before* assembly--it's inside the connections that rot begins.